# Getting row number based on value in columns - WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datagrid in wpf, for example:

age  name surname

23   Tony Cooper

28   John Doyle

35   JAmes Morisson

I know that name is Tony and surname is Cooper, now I want to find out his age. In my scenario I can't find it from the datasource, I need to find it from the table that is displayed.

How can it be done?

Thank you

Comment: for starters Tony, what does your code look like..? this would be a great place to start.. post your code..

Comment: And you mean that you cannot acces DataGrid.Items?